# Proving the variance of a random variable given R-notation

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions, variance

[Here is a picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X06Xr.png)

Basically, given that $R_X(t) = \log(M_X(t))$, I need to show that $\text{Var}(X) = R′′(0)$.

As an attempt, I know that $\text{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ and that $R'_X(0) = E(X)$, but I'm not sure how to get $E[X^2]$.

Comment: $E[X^2]$ is the second moment. You can get that from taking the 2nd derivative of the moment generating function and plugging in 0. So Var(x) =$M''(0)-[M'(0)]^2$ according to "Probability and Statistical Inference" 9th edition by Hogg, et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R_X(t)$ is called the [cumulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) of $X$, which is the natural logarithm of the moment generating function $M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}]$. It is well known that if $M_X$ is defined on an open interval containing $0$, then
$$E[X] = M'(0), \quad E[X^2] = M''(0).$$
It therefore follows that
\begin{align}
& R'(0) = \frac{M'(0)}{M(0)} = E[X] \\
& R''(0) = \frac{M''(0)M(0) - (M'(0))^2}{M(0)^2} = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 = \text{Var}(X).
\end{align}